# How to display session content in twig template

Tags: session, twig

I am new in twig.

I just would like to know how to display all session attributes using twig.

I know about the app.session but it is not a string. Probably the use of the loop.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done that way :

```
{% for key, value in app.session %}
    <li>{{ key}} / {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the nature of twig - the best way is to pass in any data you require from the controller - as a parameter.